# Tinymce truncating 'https://localhost:5001' after resolve()

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I use tinymce 6.1.0, I want to save absolute picture url after uploading, but I can't do this because tinymce truncated url and return relative url after `resolve()` executed, also tinymce doesn't truncated if I `resolve('httpls://localhost:5001/')`:

```
var editor = tinymce.init(
{
    selector: '#UpdateViewModel_HtmlContent',
    setup: function (editor)
    {
        editor.on('change', function ()
        {
            editor.save();
        });
    },
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, progress)
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append(blobInfo.filename(), blobInfo.blob());

            abp.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: abp.appPath + 'api/static/editing/content/image',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (res)
                {
                    progress && progress(100);
                    resolve('https://localhost:5001/' + res.url);
                },
                error: function (err)
                {
                    reject('Failed to upload image to server');
                },
                formData: "multipart/form-data"
            });
        });
    },
    plugins: 'image code',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',
    file_picker_types: 'image'
});
```

How to change my code?

Answer (score 1):

In `init` method I added this parameter:

```
convert_urls: false
```

This not work:

```
relative_urls: 0,
remove_script_host: 0
```